# Исключения в @Async методах. Spring

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring, исключения

Есть контекст со слушателем.

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    servletContext.addListener(SentryServletRequestListener.class);
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
}
```

и два метода. Один из них помечен аннотацией @Async

```
@Async
public void send(Long providerId, String name, String email) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}

public void load(Long providerId, String name, String email) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Слушатель реагирует на исключения НЕ асинхронных методов. 
Вопрос: можно ли настроить и как, чтобы реакция была и на исключения из АСИНХРОННЫХ методов. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Асинхронные методы выполняются в отдельном потоке, возникающие исключения в нём и остаются, вызывающий поток о них никак узнать не может. Для обработки асинхронных исключения нужно объявить отдельный слушатель:

```
public class MyAsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable throwable, Method method, Object... obj) {
        System.out.println("Exception message - " + throwable.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Method name - " + method.getName());
        for (Object param : obj) {
            System.out.println("Parameter value - " + param);
        }
    }
}
```

И зарегистрировать его в контексте:

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="someExecutorBean" exception-handler="asyncExceptionHandler"/>
<bean id="asyncExceptionHandler" class="com.example.MyAsyncExceptionHandler"/>
```

Или, если у вас используется java-конфигурация:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SpringAsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new MyAsyncExceptionHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Именно так и был решен вопрос